# PointToClient not quite working. (Error details within.)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

i'm working on a tower defence for a class exam together with a friend of mine. And i figured i would use "PointToClient" To get the positions of the cursor to send with the tower when ever we want to put it down. But its not quite working. I keep getting the error:

'Vp.PlaceTower'does not contain a definition for 'PointToClient' and no extension method 'PointToClient' accepting a first argument of type 'Vp.PlaceTower' could be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

The code is as follows;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

namespace Vp
{
    class PlaceTower : GameWorld
    {
        private List<Tower> towers = new List<Tower>();

    private Point cursorPos;
    private Point position;
    private Point oldCursorPos;

    public void PlaceTower()
    {

        cursorPos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PointToClient` is a method that belongs to the class `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. Does GameWord inherit this class? Your exception is very explanatory.
Make GameWorld inherit Control and you will solve this.

Comment: I had used this method before, so i just checked through the usings, but none of them had "Forms.Control" How ever if this is all i need to do, i would be rather happy :)